# Create column with data of the previous year and create row when dates don't have match

Tags: sql, date, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to create a column with a data of the previous year, there is one row by type and month.
However there is not in comparaison to the previous year, the current don't have a corresponding row from the previous year. Then some data are note take into account.

My table:

| TYPE | MY_DATE | Number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2023-08-01 | 300 |
| A | 2023-09-01 | 200 |
| B | 2023-10-01 | 100 |
| A | 2022-07-01 | 300 |
| A | 2022-08-01 | 300 |
| A | 2022-09-01 | 200 |
| B | 2022-10-01 | 100 |

My current code:

```
select 
    P1.type
    , P1.my_date
    , (P1.Number)
    , (P2.Number) as Number_N_1
from my_cte  as P1
full join my_cte as P2 
    on year(P1.my_date) = year(P2.my_date)+1 
    and month(P1.my_date)=month(P2.my_date)
    and P1.TYPE = P2.TYPE
```

But whit it I don't get all the values by period (month). For instance the type for the period 2023-07-01 don't In the column previous data.
My current result:

| TYPE | MY_DATE | Number | Number_n_1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2023-08-01 | 300 | 300 |
| A | 2023-09-01 | 200 | 200 |
| B | 2023-10-01 | 100 | 100 |
| A | 2022-08-01 | 300 |  |
| A | 2022-09-01 | 200 |  |
| B | 2022-10-01 | 100 |  |
| A | 2022-07-01 | 300 |  |

What I'm trying to get :

| TYPE | MY_DATE | Number | Number_n_1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2023-08-01 | 300 | 300 |
| A | 2023-09-01 | 200 | 200 |
| B | 2023-10-01 | 100 | 100 |
| **A** | **2023-07-01** | **0** | **300** |
| A | 2022-08-01 | 300 |  |
| A | 2022-09-01 | 200 |  |
| B | 2022-10-01 | 100 |  |
| A | 2022-07-01 | 300 |  |

My data sample:

```
WITH my_cte AS (
    SELECT 'A' AS type, '2023-08-01'::DATE  AS my_date, 300 as CA
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A' AS type, '2023-09-01'::DATE AS my_date, 200 as CA
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'B' AS type, '2023-10-01'::DATE AS my_date, 100 as CA
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A' AS type, '2022-07-01'::DATE  AS my_date, 300 as CA
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A' AS type, '2022-08-01'::DATE  AS my_date, 300 as CA
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A' AS type, '2022-09-01'::DATE AS my_date, 200 as CA
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'B' AS type, '2022-10-01'::DATE AS my_date, 100 as CA
)
```

Comment: so the problem you are describing, is really "how to I fill the date range I have" the "prior year part" is what you will do after you have the range gaps filled. And you appear to have that part solved, so really you just need to range between the min/max dates, join to that (to complete you date gaps) and then back project. And if you now have gapless months, you could use a lag with a step size of 12 to find the prior month, and avoid the extra join